# How do I test to see if a flex box div is set to `display:block`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

In flexbox, `display` is set to `flex`. So `$(this).css('display')` is equal to `flex`.

Since `display` has multiple settings I tried to reference it like an array, but no luck there. Trying `$(this).css('display')[1]` just gave me a single letter `l` in flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS display property can't have multiple values. It is either `block` or `flex` (or something else), it can't be both. (When a property can have multiple values, such as `text-decoration`, it usually takes a space separated list).

If it is `flex` then it isn't `block` (or `none`).

That said, `flex` is a block-style rendering. Compare to `inline-flex`.

Comment: When you apply $(this).hide() on a flex box container jquery changes display to none. So   if($(this).css('display') === 'flex')  does test  successfully.